# how to copy broken symlinks in ruby script

Tags: ruby

I want to copy all the contents from one directory to another (including broken symlinks) in my Ruby script. I am using `FileUtils.cp_r 'src/.', 'dest'` but it is complaining about the broken symlinks. Can someone please help me with this? It is a show-stopper for me right now.

Comment: A valid symlink will point to a file, but a broken bymlink will not point to a file, and so I don't think you can do anything with this in Ruby.

Comment: Can you post the exact error output you are getting?

Comment: I don't have the error message now but it was complaining about the missing file. I tried to use bash command `cp -r` as it was working. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileUtils.cp_r` internally copies the `src` folder recursively to `dest`.  When it finds a symlink, it will create a symlink using [`File#symlink`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html#method-c-symlink) method (Refer line 1369 of [fileutils.rb](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_2/lib/fileutils.rb)).

The documentation of [`File#symlink`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html#method-c-symlink) states that:

> Creates a symbolic link called new_name for the **existing file**
>   old_name. Raises a NotImplemented exception on platforms that do not
>   support symbolic links.

So, it seems that it may not be possible to use FileUtils.cp_r to copy directories if the one of the symlinks in it is broken and pointing to a non-existing file.

**Workaround**

You can execute shell command `cp -r` command from your ruby script, it may not be platform-independent code and may not be easy to debug, but it will help you to get around the given scenario which you consider to be a *show-stopper*.

```
src = "/path/to/src/dir"
dest = "/path/to/dest/dir"

`cp -r #{src} #{dest}`
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did the same thing but shell `cp -r` is not that fast as Ruby `cp_r`. I am thinking of using some logic to use shell `cp` only for broken links and for rest of them use Ruby `cp_r`. Wanted to check which one is faster. Will post my answer either way. Thanks again.